# Why my sqlite code is not recognizing my table? discord.py

Tags: python, database, sqlite, discord, discord.py

Why my sqlite database table is giving me this error even if i do have a table?

[image: cog files]

**CODE**

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    db = sqlite3.connect('banco.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT nome FROM banco WHERE nome = "{message.author.id}"')
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        sql = ('INSERT INTO banco(nome, dinheiro) VALUES(?, ?)')
        val = (message.author.id, 0)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
    db.comit()
    cursor.close()
```

**ERROR:**

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/CIP/Documents/GitHub/economia/cogs/dinheiro.py", line 56, in on_message
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT nome FROM banco WHERE nome = "{message.author.id}"')
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: banco
```

**LINE**

```
cursor.execute(f'SELECT nome FROM banco WHERE nome = "{message.author.id}"')
```

Comment: get you query and test directly in database. Error shows that you don't have table `banco` in your database. Maybe you use wrong file `.db` or you removed all data at start. Or code runs in different folder then you expect and then it uses file from different folder - check `print( os.getcwd() )` (`Current Working Directory`)

Comment: have you made sure you have written the changes to the database so it knows there is a table?